# Run function only after paypal transaction success and redirected to my page

Tags: php, security, paypal

I am building an page with some items that I gonna sell through `paypal`. first I did generic buttons with fixed prices,after clicking you redirected to paypal page with your values like that:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top" class="payPalBtn">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="test@gmail.com">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="test">
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="10.00">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/he_IL/IL/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

But this is to dangerous because the client can change the amount value...and it can make some problems. So I chose using their API - this means, on server side sending some values like price,amount... ang getting back `token id`. After that sending this again with some data, and in the end the payment is transferred and every thing is closed. One of the parameters is: $`PayPalReturnURL` , this the page after success result, the user redirected to.

Now after I did that and verified that the payment pass I want to start an private program that do some private function (each time I run it it cost me money) that should be done only once, after the payment passed. The page I redirect is for example :  payment.php, and there I simply start my function.

The question is: how can I be sure that the user wont go straight to that PHP address and automatically start this function. what are my options guarantee that this function would run only once after paypal redirect to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making it complex. Here is how I did paypal integration.

Alone with the input price send the transaction no in a hidden field as below.

```
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="10.00">
<input type="hidden" name="tx_id" value="1234">
```

Before generation this form insert a database record with the status of the transaction as pending as below.

```
tx_id = 1234
amount = 10.00
tx_status = 0 // pending
```

When the transaction is complete paypal will return amount, your tx_id and status of the transaction. Using a SELECT query you can check whether returned amount is the same amount whether in the database table.

```
SELECT amount FROM table_name WHERE tx_id = 1234
```

Then If it's correct change the tx_status to paid. Else mark it as fraud.

Comment: You right @Dasun but I choose to work with there API, because client can basically change the `tx_i`f and `amount`, and play with those values...

Comment: tx_id is generated by you for your reference only.

Comment: If user changes it your validation fails. so no issues

Comment: do you have an web site example? I'd like to check it closely

Answer (score 0):

To protect your button you could either setup a hosted button through [Payments Standard](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/wp_standard_overview/) or you could integrate the [Express Checkout API](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_expresscheckout_integrationguide.pdf) if you're familiar with using web services.

As for the automated post-order processing you won't want to do that on your return URL.  There is no guarantee that page will get hit even with Auto-Return enabled in your PayPal account.  If the buyer closes their browser before that redirect happens your code will never run and your automation will not work correctly.

To avoid this, and to protect from people going directly to your return URL, you can utilize [Instant Payment Notification](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/).  This will be triggered with every payment regardless of whether the user makes it back to your site or not, and you can verify the data with PayPal to ensure it actually came from them so people can't try to be sneaky with your IPN script.